# How do I make this Delivery calculator more efficient?

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a simple JavaScript function that will allow a website visitor to see how much it would cost for a company to deliver to there location. It is simply a function that has them select there city from a drop down menu and then it will display the price. Below is how I decided to define the variable that I wish to print.

```
var delivery=document.getElementById("delivery").value; //id of selection box

var deliveryCharge;
if (delivery=="None")
{
deliveryCharge=0;
}
else if (delivery=="Acworth")
{
deliveryCharge=175;
}
else if (delivery=="Alpharetta")
{
deliveryCharge=140;
}
```

Then I use...

```
document.getElementById("charge").innerHTML="$" + deliveryCharge.toFixed(2);
```

to show the amount. The problem is that there are 400 locations that I will need to put in the HTML input and in the JavaScript. What I would like to know is how you all would approach this function, is there a more efficient way so that I do not have to write 400 else if statements? (p.s) there is no mathematical correlation between locations and price.)

Thank you all in advance for your time and responses.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What's your site running on?  As in, what's on the backend? Is there a db you could add this to?

Comment: you can have the charges on a database or even a json file and the just match the selected id, or you can use arrays with key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, use an object:

```
var deliveryCharges = {
    "None": 0,
    "Alpharetta": 400,
    "Test": 200
};
function getDeliveryCharge(type) {
    var currentType = type || "None"; // undefined and null out of the way.
    if (typeof deliveryCharges[currentType] !== 'undefined') {// No error thrown here.
        return deliveryCharges[currentType];// type recognized return it
    } else {
        return 0;// type not found, just return 0;
    };
};
```

Now to actually get it:

```
var delivery= getDeliveryCharge(document.getElementById("delivery").value);
```

Comment: So I understand how to make the map and objects but how do I use those to relay the totals that match beck to the user?

Comment: Thank you for the response this will work great. Thank you for adding the comments, always helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The first think that comes to mind is a map, like so:

```
var map = {
    'None': 0,
    'Acworth': 175,
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `object` options already suggested, I'd definitely suggest dropping this approach and going for a more flexible approach. Cities and municipalities are merged and created on a yearly basis, so maintaining your collection is going to be hell. I'd recommend using an Ajax callback to the server, where you can invoke the Google Maps API to provide a guesstimate of the actual distance to the delivery location, and then apply a simple formula to it (if need be only if it's not in a predefined set of costs for nearby cities).

Comment: Thank you for the response, I think this will be a great idea for the future when my skills are a little better developed.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Alberto's answer, perhaps also divide the delivery locations into zones, then map your locations to those zones?  That way you can change a whole group of delivery prices at the same time when your costs change.  (Change the zone price rather than 37 individual prices that are within the same zone.)

This may be less efficient in code, but quite a bit more efficient for maintainability.

(Unless, of course, all 400 locations truly have a unique price.  Then there's no need.)